# How to Login through facebook in Wordpress website?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, authentication

I have a website in Wordpress.
I want user to login through Facebook and redirect to my website .
I applied several plugins but they redirect me to facebook.
I dont want to go on Facebook .Only Login through facebook and enter the Home page of my Website .
and then can like on my website too .

Answer (score 0):

The way Facebook login works...requires the visitor to login with a Facebook generated page. The reason for this is that Facebook doesn't trust other web developers and needs to prevent them from capturing the visitor's facebook login credentials.

The way the Facebook login plugins work...is the way you will have to live with logging in with facebook. There is no alternative (other than not letting them use facebook to login).

On the plus side, most people are always logged into facebook, so they won't have to enter their credentials. They will only have to authorize your website to look at their facebook stuff.